# trac syntax highlitings on comments

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting, highlight, trac, pygments

I installed pygments on my trac server. but the code is without colours on the ticket comments.

this is what i have on trac.ini :

```
[mimeviewer]
max_preview_size = 262144
mime_map = text/x-dylan:dylan,text/x-idl:ice,text/x-ada:ads:adb,text/x-               java:java,application/x-python:py python sage
pygments_default_style = trac
pygments_modes = text/plain:java:7
silvercity_modes =
tab_width = 8
treat_as_binary = application/octet-stream,application/pdf,application/postscript,application/msword,application/rtf,
```

this is what i am writing in the comments:
    `{{{ #!java if(var=='true') {     a ='hi'; } }}}`

many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you've formatted your markup correctly. Please try:

```
{{{#!java 
if(var=='true') { a ='hi'; }
}}}
```

To confirm that Pygments is installed correctly, check the `about` page and make sure the version is listed in the **System Information** table.

Which version of Trac and which version of Pygments? You need Trac 1.0.3 or later (preferably 1.0.4) with Pygments 2.x. See [#11796](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11796). You should install [Pygments 1.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygments/1.6) if you are stuck with an earlier version of Trac.

Comment: hello, yes the code was ok.
Trac version is 0.12.3

Pygments is not listed in System Information table. do you know how i can add it?

Comment: Using the information you reported in [#11961](trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11961): delete `/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Pygments-2.0.2-py2.6.egg` and `easy_install pygments==1.6`.